# Should name of programming language be in the title of a question?

Tags: discussion, tags, site-policy, titles

Almost every question on the website has the name of the programming language in its title. Also words like feedback, review etc. are unneeded I think as that is this website's purpose.

I wanted the opinion of the community about should it be present or not? Should edits be done on such questions?

Answer (score 15):

If the programming language is not integrated into the title, something like:

- C++ - Reading n chars from stream to string
- [C++] Reading n chars from stream to string
- C++ Reading n chars from stream to string
- Reading n chars from stream to string - C++

then all it does is to act as a something like tag. And that's what actual tags are for, so you should edit the title to remove the language and add it among the tags of the question if it's not there yet.

If the language is actually grammatically part of the title, something like:

- Reading n chars from stream to string in C++

then I think it's still redundant and that it would be okay to remove it. But it doesn't pollute the title as much, so I usually tend to leave it there.

Answer (score 7):

I have no problems with [feedback, reviews, etc] in the title as long as it accompanies the type of program in some form.  For instance, I'm okay with this:

*Cleaning code in binary tree structure*

...as opposed to this:

*Cleaning code in this program*

While they both accomplish these things:

- You know right away that the question IS on-topic
- If you're not good with the review type and prefer not to perform other reviews, then you can skip the question

...*only* the former accomplishes this as well:

- If you're familiar that program type and/or it piques your interest, you'll want to review that question.  This is especially important *if* you don't want to extensively review *every* question for your particular programming language(s).

Bearing that in mind, I agree that the question *should* be edited if it's comparable to the latter.  Whether or not they're reflective of the post's contents, it could look quite unattractive.

As for the programming language in the title, I also agree that it's unnecessary.  Every question should include its appropriate language tag(s).  If you see a question without a language tag, whether or not it's included in the title, the tag should be added.  If there is a language tag and it's also mentioned in the title, then I'd leave it alone unless there are other necessary edits.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to reinvent the wheel, just additional elaboration on what has already been said.

I agree with [this here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/223277).
Which is an extension of @svick's answer, but gives more detail and an example of a title that needs language as part of question and not as a tag.

If the language does not pertain to the actual question, it should be omitted.

Example being a question relating to the differences in python and jython, with jython's relationship to java.

> How come I can do this in jython, but not in python?

Comment: Nice. That helps.

Comment: @AseemBansal cool, I love SE, particularly SO and meta, looks like this is a great site and I was recommended to come here, happy to help :)

Comment: @AseemBansal sorry didn't see the vote, and it has not registered.. but it's more the principal of voting (as you know), I encourage new users to do this also) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950342/using-serialport-in-second-form/17950525#comment26234204_17950342