# "Flood" of "Doing something in [language]" titles

Tags: discussion, titles

I always thought that questions containing a language tag in the title should be cleaned-up as discussed in *[Should name of programming language be in the title of a question?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/767/should-name-of-programming-language-be-in-the-title-of-a-question)*

Apparently I'm the only person doing this and we're getting virtually flooded by them:

- [A little next combination program **in C++**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/190982/a-little-next-combination-program-in-c)
- [Noughts and crosses bot **in Delphi**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/190764/noughts-and-crosses-bot-in-delphi)
- [Mimic C#'s nameof() **in Python**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/186404/mimic-cs-nameof-in-python)
- [Objects moving on a grid **in C++** [on hold]](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/190983/objects-moving-on-a-grid-in-c)
- [Best accuracy and performance with timers **in JS**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/190962/best-accuracy-and-performance-with-timers-in-js)
- [Moving files and leaving links **in bash**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/190960/moving-files-and-leaving-links-in-bash)
- [Chip 8 Emulator **in JavaScript**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/190905/chip-8-emulator-in-javascript)
- [Optimizing priority queue streaming algorithm **in C++**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/190958/optimizing-priority-queue-streaming-algorithm-in-c)
- [Async File Input **C++**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/190955/async-file-input-c)
- [Trading card game **in Python**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/190876/trading-card-game-in-python)
- [A little stock market game **in Python**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/190882/a-little-stock-market-game-in-python)
- [Hash table with separate chaining implementation **in C**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/190873/hash-table-with-separate-chaining-implementation-in-c)

and these are only a couple of examples.

I was wondering, do you we have new site standards or how should they be treated?

I find all such titles were better off without the *in language* suffix especially that some of them got their suffix by *fixing* them from *language - Doing something* to *Doing something in language*.

Comment: A typical StackOverflow question is called "Creating a game payment server in Java" which is actually read as "Please locate a mistake in the third loop inside the fifth method of my class".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's true that language in a title should be avoided whenever possible.

There is another obstacle though that we need to deal with. Given the way Code Review works, there are essentially no duplicates. We tell you what *you* need to know, even if you've done the same "mistakes" as some others before you. So this inevitably leads to a lot of "Noughts and crosses bot"-like questions.

However, I think some of these titles comes from the fact that...

[image: A question with that title already exists: please be more specific]

Users are just not allowed to put the exact same title on their post as other people already have.

There are other details that can be added in a title though:

- What distinguishes your approach? Hardcoded? Flexible? MVC? Event-driven?
- Is it available to use for others? Then your title could start with "Try my" or similar.
- Tell a story! Or a bad joke. Or something.
- Plenty of other different things too...

Comment: This. I'm a big fan of removing languages from titles, but with the amount of questions we get for the same problems, keeping the language tag is the easy way out.

Comment: I'm highly in favor of making your title unique however many people might be unable to come up with a good title due to limitations of their english knowledge. I think native speakers have an advantage here and should feel free to edit titles more often (Jamal does a good job at this but we can't expect him to do all the editing alone).

Comment: [Vue - It's the Royal Game of Ur](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/190896/vue-its-the-royal-game-of-ur) - uhm, not giving the best example with this title :-]

Comment: @t3chb0t At least Vue is a framework and not a language, and also attempt at a bad pun as Vue is supposedly pronounced similar to "View" :)